# Post/submit a file using submit_form routine of WWW::Mechanize module

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am following guidelines

> If you want to submit a file and get its content from a scalar rather than a file in the filesystem, you can use:

```
$mech->submit_form(with_fields => { logfile => [ [ undef, 'whatever', Content => $content ], 1 ] } );
```

from WWW::Mechanize [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Esubmit_form(_..._))

My code to submit a file

```
$mech->submit_form(with_fields => 
            { logfile => [ [ undef, "import_codes.xlsx", Content => $file_dir ], 1 ] });
```

Its failing with exception;

```
Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1568.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1568.
    WWW::Mechanize::set_fields('WWW::Mechanize=HASH(0xf51b040)', 'logfile', 'ARRAY(0xf71e6dc)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1948
    WWW::Mechanize::submit_form('WWW::Mechanize=HASH(0xf51b040)', 'form_name', 'inputform', 'fields', 'HASH(0xf71e920)')
```

Code snippet of Mechanize.pm from line 1560 to 1575.

```
sub set_fields {
    my $self = shift;
    my %fields = @_;

    my $form = $self->current_form or $self->die( 'No form defined' );

    while ( my ( $field, $value ) = each %fields ) {
        if ( ref $value eq 'ARRAY' ) {
            $form->find_input( $field, undef,
                         $value->[1])->value($value->[0] );
        }
        else {
            $form->value($field => $value);
        }
    } # while
}
```

Comment: Your `submit_form` is missing the closing paren `)`. Is that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: yes, its copy/paste mistake, my code compiles and executes.

Comment: Please fix it. Which version of WWW::Mechanize is this? In the latest one the `set_fields` method is [in line 793](https://v1.metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#L793).

Comment: Oh. What's the `logfile`? Is that the name of the form field? Do you have a form input like that in your target form?

Comment: thanks @simbabque, actually you had pointed out the issue in one go.

Comment: I saw it, wrote the comment, then went to read documentation and wrote an answer. If you'd replied in the meantime I had voted to close as non-reproducible because of a typo. The important thing is it's working now. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong field name for the file input field in the form. (Emphasis mine).

> If you want to submit a file and get its content from a scalar rather than a file in the filesystem, you can use:
>
> ```
>                                     vvvvvvv
> $mech->submit_form(with_fields => { logfile => [ [ undef, 'whatever', Content => $content ], 1 ] } );
> ```

That `logfile` is the name attribute of the input field that you want the file content to be placed in. In their example it's *logfile*, but in your real form on the website you're trying to submit it's likely something else.

[`$mech->submit_form`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-submit_form) calls [`$mech->form_with_fields`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-form_with_fields-fields). The docs for that method say:

> Returns undef if no form is found.

When it then does `set_fields` it will fail because `undef` was returned.

**Use the correct field name and it should work.**

Comment: Yes you are right, in this particular form input name if file.